# How to show each element in the HTML page?

Tags: go

**Requirement**

Hey there, I am trying to show the comments on an HTML page. Although it prints every comment in the terminal but does not show every comment on an HTML page. Instead, it shows only the first row.

**Code info**

After finding the data of comments in the database, I printed every comment in the terminal using the multidimensional array but it was difficult to write `x` and `y` each time. That's why I created two `for-loops` and a third loop to assign numbers to the `values` variable.

```
mdArray := [][]string{
    values[0:4],
    values[4:8],
        // x:y        
}
```

I used `mdArray` in the `CommentData{}` structure to assign values to the variables. After printing the data, it shows every comment that is inserted but when I return this function to be executed on the HTML page, it only prints the first row.

**Code**

```
type CommentData struct {
    Fname   string
    Lname   string
    Email   string
    Message string
    Date    string
    Time    string
}

func SendData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) CommentData {
    note := models.AddComment{
        Fname:   r.FormValue("fname"),
        Lname:   r.FormValue("lname"),
        Email:   r.FormValue("email"),
        Message: r.FormValue("message"),
    }
    dt := time.Now()
    date := dt.Format("02-Jan-2006")
    time := dt.Format("15:04:05")
    values1 := [6]string{note.Fname, note.Lname, note.Email, note.Message, date, time}

    _, match := database.FindAccount(note.Fname, note.Lname, note.Email)
    if match {
        database.InsertComment(values1)
        values2 := database.FindComment(note.Fname, note.Lname, note.Email)
        var store1, store2 []int
        for i := 0; i <= len(values2); i++ {
            if i%6 == 0 {
                store1 = append(store1, i)
            }
        }
        for j := 6; j <= len(values2); j++ {
            if j%6 == 0 {
                store2 = append(store2, j)
            }
        }
        for i := 0; i < len(store2); i++ {
            mdArray := [][]string{
                values2[store1[i]:store2[i]],
            }
            // fmt.Println(mdArray[0][3])
            hello := CommentData{
                Fname:   mdArray[0][0],
                Lname:   mdArray[0][1],
                Email:   mdArray[0][2],
                Message: mdArray[0][3],
                Date:    "On " + mdArray[0][4],
                Time:    "At " + mdArray[0][5],
            }
            fmt.Println(hello)
            return hello
        }
    } else {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", http.StatusFound)
    }
    return CommentData{}
}

func FirstBlog(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        return FirstBlogTmpl.Execute(w, nil)
    } else if r.Method == "POST" {
        Newsletter(w, r)
        hello := SendData(w, r)
        return FirstBlogTmpl.Execute(w, hello)
    }
    return nil
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>                                   
    {{.}}
</div>
```

Comment: @CeriseLimón I declared the global variable and return it but still didn't the required result.

Comment: Even if you un-comment `return note`, `return CommentData{}` is problematic. Can you please provide an updated code example? Also, you're never writing anything on your `http.ResponseWriter`. Are you perhaps using a framework that is handling that for you?

Comment: @CeriseLimón Yes, the `CommentData{}` contains multiple `Fname`, `Lname`, `Email` and `Message` and I want to return all of them that are present in the database.

Comment: @Dean You can see the three dots `...` above. I used `http.ResponseWriter` in an `if-statement` in which I put condition to check whether the account is logged in or not. If it is logged in then execute this code, otherwise `http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", http.StatusFound)`.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I updated the code. You see it.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I updated the code by adding `FirstBlog()` function at the end, in which it writes the comments. You can now see it.

Comment: @CeriseLimón How?

Comment: @CeriseLimón It shows the result like this. `{name email@gmail.com messsage On 12-Jan-2022 At 11:34:05}`

Comment: Is there anyone to answer my question?

Comment: @CeriseLimón I used `[]string{}` to convert struct into slice and it printed all of the data but when I return it, it does not work.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I am waiting for your answer. **It prints all the comments but when I return, it just gives me the first row.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put resultatos in a slice:

```
    … ​
   ​var hellos []CommentData
   ​for i := 0; i < len(store2); i++ {
       ​mdArray := [][]string{
           ​values2[store1[i]:store2[i]],
       ​}
       ​// fmt.Println(mdArray[0][3])
       ​hello := CommentData{
           ​Fname:   mdArray[0][0],
           ​Lname:   mdArray[0][1],
           ​Email:   mdArray[0][2],
           ​Message: mdArray[0][3],
           ​Date:    "On " + mdArray[0][4],
           ​Time:    "At " + mdArray[0][5],
       ​}
       ​fmt.Println(hello)
       ​hellos = append(hellos, hello)
   ​}
   ​return hellos
   ​…
```

Change function return type return type []CommentData.

Range over the resultatos in the template

```
{{range .}}
<div>
{{.}}
</div>
```